# Look up for DOM element by XPath, starting from other DOM element

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

I found that in Chrome DevTools it is suggested to use `$x` for XPath expressions lookups. But what if one already gets the desired DOM element and wants to continue searching, or may be wants to get some parents attributes.

Is there a way to use `$x` search starting from the given DOM element (treating this element as a DOM root)?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I start digging into DevTools just recently and don't know all those tricks you've gratefully supplied! They are all good starting points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$x
```

in the Google Chrome console and it outputs

```
ƒ $x(xpath, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

so that suggests there is an optional second argument to be treated as the context node or start node.

For instance on this page when I use

```
var codeElements = $x('//*[. = "$x"]');
```

I get

```
(5) [code, code, pre.lang-xml.prettyprint.prettyprinted, code, span.pln]
```

in the console for `codeElements` and when I use

```
var parentElements = codeElements.map(el => $x('..', el)[0]);
```

to compute the parent node of each item in the `codeElements` array I get

```
(5) [p, p, div#wmd-preview.wmd-preview, pre.lang-xml.prettyprint.prettyprinted, code]
```

for `parentElements`.

So you can pass in the context node as the second argument to `$x`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$x` accepts a second argument named `startNode` which, as its name suggests, is exactly what you are looking for.

You can use it like this:

```
var myNode = document.getElementById('myId'); // obtain any node in any manner you need to
var childElements = $x('*', myNode);
console.log(childElements.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you need to use an xpath expression to start from one specific tag, then jump to another tag or get attributes, 
Example

```
//span[@id='test23']//..//a[@id='233']
```

Also using keywords like "ancestor", "following", "following-sibling"etc.

I suggest you lookup more on Xpath on the net